# Power BI How to remove duplicate rows under specific conditions keeping the latest entry?

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Hello I need help removing duplicate rows under certain conditions.

| Raw File |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ANI | Date | Time |
| 111-111-1111 | 8/7/2022 | 10:34:00 AM |
| 111-111-1111 | 8/7/2022 | 12:00:00 PM |
| 111-111-1111 | 8/7/2022 | 12:03:00 PM |
| 222-222-2222 | 8/8/2022 | 10:50:00 AM |
| 222-222-2222 | 8/8/2022 | 10:52:10 AM |
| 333-333-3333 | 8/9/2022 | 12:29:00 PM |
| 333-333-3333 | 8/9/2022 | 12:32:00 PM |
| 333-333-3333 | 8/9/2022 | 12:33:00 PM |
| 444-444-4444 | 8/10/2022 | 1:50:00 PM |
| 444-444-4444 | 8/10/2022 | 1:51:00 PM |

Raw File contains ANI column which shows different phone numbers called into my system,

Date and Time columns matching the time which the calls came in.

I want to remove the earliest entries of the back-to-back calls based on the same number and date only if called in within 3 minutes after the initial call.

This is the end result that I wish to my Power BI would see and count:

| Result |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ANI | Date | Time |
| 111-111-1111 | 8/7/2022 | 10:34:00 AM |
| 111-111-1111 | 8/7/2022 | 12:03:00 PM |
| 222-222-2222 | 8/8/2022 | 10:52:10 AM |
| 333-333-3333 | 8/9/2022 | 12:33:00 PM |
| 444-444-4444 | 8/10/2022 | 1:51:00 PM |

At the end, I want it to count the back-to-back calls just once if called in within 3 min time frame and leave alone singular calls made outside of that condition.

Please help.

Comment: Please paste your sample data as text so it can be copied.

Comment: Help others to help you!

Comment: Google knows: https://tableconvert.com/markdown-generator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of doing this using the Query Editor:
*See the comments to help understand the algorithm*

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("jc8xCoAwDIXhq0hni8lLRO3mAQT30vtfw1qiZCodfsjwwSM5B2aOFoc57Mu2gIB6MiXRRDSdVyhzV6KyV94jUpwEEC00ubv1ldx6XyLxL0UkWtLk4dZxuPWuFAxL/5GqRkubZPqpfTQk+ZPlAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ANI = _t, Date = _t, Time = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ANI", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}}),

//create a column with the combine datetime
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "DateTime", each [Date]&[Time], type datetime),

//group by ANI
// for each ANI group
//     Sort by datetime
//     Add a shifted column to compare one row to the next
//     Retain only those rows where the difference between the original and the next column is greater than 3 minutes
//        or the last row which will have a null in the shifted column
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"ANI"}, {
        {"Filtered", (t)=>
            let 
                sorted = Table.Sort(t,{"DateTime", Order.Ascending}),
                shifted = Table.FromColumns(
                        Table.ToColumns(t) & {List.RemoveFirstN(t[DateTime],1) & {null}},
                        type table[ANI=text, Date=date, Time=time, DateTime=datetime, Shifted=datetime]),
                deleteRows = Table.SelectRows(shifted, each [Shifted] = null or Duration.TotalMinutes([Shifted] - [DateTime]) > 3)
            in 
                deleteRows, type table[ANI=text, Date=date, Time=time]}
            }),

//re-expand the groups
    #"Expanded Filtered" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Filtered", {"Date", "Time"})
in
    #"Expanded Filtered"
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent solution and probably much faster than my own.

Comment: It's a good habit to use the final `culture` argument for the `#"Changed Type"` step.  That makes date and time conversions deterministic.

Comment: @ninMonkey I find that useful when you know the data input will always be characterized by a specific culture, and the user may be using a different culture.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("lc8xCoAwDIXhq0hnS5OXiNrNAwju4v2voaVRs1WHHzJ8w8u+B2aOFnehD1MaEwgoN1MWzUTdsoajb1hcsNjtmxVnAUQL1U5+w0BuQ8si82NFJFpS7ew3YHYbGlbww/rfVDVaWi3Ti+23j5Zve5w=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ANI = _t, Date = _t, Time = _t]),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(Source,{"Date", "Time"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns", {{"Merged", type datetime}}, "en-US"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type with Locale",{{"ANI", Order.Ascending}, {"Merged", Order.Descending}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Custom", each 
try
    if [ANI] = #"Sorted Rows"[ANI]{[Index] - 1} and  #"Sorted Rows"[Merged]{[Index] - 1} -[Merged]  <= #duration(0,0,3,0)   then true else false
otherwise false
),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([Custom] = false)),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "Custom"}),
    #"Inserted Date" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Date", each DateTime.Date([Merged]), type date),
    #"Inserted Time" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Date", "Time", each DateTime.Time([Merged]), type time),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Time",{"Merged"})
in
    #"Removed Columns1"
```