# PowerQuery / How to remove duplicate rows under specific conditions keeping the first entry?

Tags: powerquery

I have almost the same needs as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73407128/power-bi-how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-under-specific-conditions-keeping-the-late), from which my title is based.
Here's my list :
[table screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvCXS.png)
Same as data :

| ID | Version | ModificationDateTime | StatutModifié |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:46 | Abandon |
| 1 | 1 | 14/12/2020 21:43:03 | Abandon |
| 2 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:46 | Affaire |
| 2 | 1 | 18/08/2021 17:08:41 | Affaire |
| 3 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:46 | Affaire |
| 3 | 1 | 09/02/2021 19:23:18 | Affaire |
| 4 | 4 | 25/07/2023 15:22:45 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 4 | 3 | 13/01/2023 16:17:08 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 4 | 2 | 13/01/2023 16:14:13 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 4 | 1 | 14/06/2021 16:29:51 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 5 | 1 | 10/11/2020 22:56:41 | Abandon |
| 6 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:46 | Affaire |
| 6 | 1 | 28/10/2021 15:16:29 | Affaire |
| 7 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:46 | Perte |
| 7 | 1 | 30/04/2021 14:14:15 | Perte |
| 8 | 5 | 20/06/2023 15:10:14 | Abandon |
| 8 | 4 | 20/06/2023 15:10:09 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 8 | 3 | 13/01/2023 16:17:09 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 8 | 2 | 13/01/2023 16:14:15 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 8 | 1 | 27/08/2021 18:19:16 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 9 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:47 | Affaire |
| 9 | 1 | 09/02/2021 20:15:30 | Affaire |
| 10 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:47 | Affaire |
| 10 | 1 | 01/06/2021 16:56:46 | Affaire |
| 11 | 1 | 18/08/2021 17:11:58 | Perte |
| 12 | 3 | 08/11/2022 16:20:47 | Abandon |
| 12 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:18:25 | Abandon |
| 12 | 1 | 18/08/2021 17:08:48 | Abandon |
| 13 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:20:47 | Perte |
| 13 | 1 | 19/11/2020 12:47:15 | Perte |
| 14 | 1 | 05/06/2021 15:23:26 | Perte |
| 15 | 1 | 04/05/2021 12:28:46 | Perte |
| 16 | 8 | 20/06/2023 15:09:34 | Abandon |
| 16 | 7 | 20/06/2023 15:09:15 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 16 | 6 | 13/01/2023 16:19:26 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 16 | 5 | 13/01/2023 16:17:10 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 16 | 4 | 13/01/2023 16:14:16 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 16 | 3 | 08/11/2022 16:20:47 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 16 | 2 | 08/11/2022 16:18:25 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 16 | 1 | 05/10/2021 19:04:03 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 116 | 16 | 21/03/2023 11:12:36 | Perte |
| 116 | 15 | 21/03/2023 11:12:06 | Perte |
| 116 | 14 | 13/01/2023 16:19:20 | Attente accord client |
| 116 | 13 | 13/01/2023 16:16:55 | Attente accord client |
| 116 | 12 | 13/01/2023 16:14:00 | Attente accord client |
| 116 | 11 | 21/07/2022 16:16:45 | Attente accord client |
| 116 | 10 | 21/07/2022 16:16:32 | Attente accord client |
| 116 | 9 | 01/07/2022 17:16:48 | Offre à monter |
| 116 | 8 | 10/06/2022 12:54:59 | Offre à monter |
| 116 | 7 | 10/06/2022 12:51:40 | Offre à monter |
| 116 | 6 | 10/06/2022 12:51:28 | Offre à monter |
| 116 | 5 | 10/06/2022 12:50:43 | Offre à monter |
| 116 | 4 | 10/06/2022 12:50:40 | Abandon |
| 116 | 3 | 11/05/2022 22:32:19 | Abandon |
| 116 | 2 | 11/05/2022 22:31:44 | Abandon |
| 116 | 1 | 15/11/2021 12:13:24 | Attente accord client |

I'm tracking some changes on a SharePoint list used as a CRM.
In my case, differencies are on datatypes, condition different and the fact I want to keep the first entry rather than the last one.

I successfully applied Davide Bacci's solution (big thanks to him for this sharing) but it runs (very) slowly (more than half an hour) for my 300 rows. Maybe Table.Buffer could help but I ignore this function.
Here's is the result I'm expecting :

| ID | Version | ModificationDateTime | StatutModifié |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 14/12/2020 21:43:03 | Abandon |
| 2 | 1 | 18/08/2021 17:08:41 | Affaire |
| 3 | 1 | 09/02/2021 19:23:18 | Affaire |
| 4 | 1 | 14/06/2021 16:29:51 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 5 | 1 | 10/11/2020 22:56:41 | Abandon |
| 6 | 1 | 28/10/2021 15:16:29 | Affaire |
| 7 | 1 | 30/04/2021 14:14:15 | Perte |
| 8 | 1 | 27/08/2021 18:19:16 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 9 | 1 | 09/02/2021 20:15:30 | Affaire |
| 10 | 1 | 01/06/2021 16:56:46 | Affaire |
| 11 | 1 | 18/08/2021 17:11:58 | Perte |
| 12 | 1 | 18/08/2021 17:08:48 | Abandon |
| 13 | 1 | 19/11/2020 12:47:15 | Perte |
| 14 | 1 | 05/06/2021 15:23:26 | Perte |
| 15 | 1 | 04/05/2021 12:28:46 | Perte |
| 16 | 6 | 13/01/2023 16:19:26 | Offre à monter |
| 16 | 3 | 08/11/2022 16:20:47 | Besoin à comprendre |
| 16 | 1 | 05/10/2021 19:04:03 | Stand-by/report besoin |
| 116 | 15 | 21/03/2023 11:12:06 | Perte |
| 116 | 10 | 21/07/2022 16:16:32 | Attente accord client |
| 116 | 5 | 10/06/2022 12:50:43 | Offre à monter |
| 116 | 2 | 11/05/2022 22:31:44 | Abandon |
| 116 | 1 | 15/11/2021 12:13:24 | Attente accord client |

(most relevant set of data here are items with ID 16 & 116)

Trying Ron Rosenfled solution from previous post, I fail with a datatype error so I'm surely missing something. Error happens when comparing content on deleteRows step

Here's the last part of my code, based on previous post, which fails

```
    #"Colonnes groupées" = Table.Group(#"Minimal", {"ID"}, {
        {"Filtered", (t)=>
            let
                sorted = Table.Sort(t,{"Version", Order.Descending}),
                shifted = Table.FromColumns(
                    Table.ToColumns(t) & {List.RemoveFirstN(t[Version],1) & {null}},
                    type table[ID=number, Version=number, ModificationDateTime=datetime, StatutModifié=text, ShiftedStatus=text]),
                deleteRows = Table.SelectRows(shifted, each [ShiftedStatus] = null or Text.Contains([ShiftedStatus], [StatutModifié], Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            in
                deleteRows, type table[ID=number, Version=number, ModificationDateTime=datetime, StatutModifié=text]}
            }),
    #"Expanded" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Colonnes groupées", "Filtered", {"Version","ModificationDateTime","StatutModifié"})
in
    #"Expanded"
```

Any help/hint appreciated (and sorry for uncomplete first post)

Comment: To make your **data** useful **edit your question** to post it as **text** which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Also, tell the first step that shows the error, and the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, try this code:

***Edit: `GroupKind.Local` added to `Table.Group function`***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Version", Int64.Type}, {"ModificationDateTime", type datetime}, {"StatutModifié", type text}},"en-150"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID", "StatutModifié"}, {
        {"Min", (t)=>
        Table.FromRecords(
        {Record.SelectFields(Table.Min(t,"ModificationDateTime"),{"Version","ModificationDateTime"})}),
        type table[Version=Int64.Type, ModificationDateTime=datetime]}}, GroupKind.Local),
    #"Expanded Min" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Min", {"Version", "ModificationDateTime"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Expanded Min",{"ID", "Version", "ModificationDateTime", "StatutModifié"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

The code does not check for items with the same ID coming in within a certain time frame, but you have not stated what that might be, and you have not provided a data sample that shows the issues.

The above code creates a table identical to your expected result.

***Results for your data as of `2023-12-10 1903Z`***
[image]

Comment: edited my first post as required and with more relevant data (sorry), reading your code I'm not sure it's what I'm expecting

Comment: @Ge0 Not sure exactly what you are "expecting" since my code generates a table identical to your expected result. You have changed it a bit, so I just removed the `Sort` step and changed the name of the `Status` column to fit with your posted data. Since your problem was speed, you should compare the speeds of the two approaches.

Comment: You're correct, I edited my data a bit since my initial ones weren't signifiant, and I thought the result was not as expected since my "real" data are different too... I'm still a bit confused by the fact your approach is quite different from the initial post where you were grabing data from next row, whereas you're using kind of "subgrouping" here. What would be the behaviour of your code if the StatutModifié field go back to a previous value ? Would the output table contain the two rows for each change ?

Comment: But this new approach is terrific with duration : around 1 min versus more than 30

Comment: @Ge0 this is a different problem than the previous so there is no need to check the previous row. For questions as to how the code might behave under circumstances that you did not post above, I suggest you test it.

Comment: Of course I'm gonna try, but I asked since I was not sure about having such a data set in my real source. I found one, I have edited the original post with a new ID, 116

Comment: I confirm the behaviour I suspected, I get only 4 rows with ID 116 (one for each status) instead of 5. This is the reason why, at first sight, I wanted to try your implementation of the initial problem, checking the value of the row below to remove it if status was the same. I should have started with this data set from the begining to make myself clear

Comment: @Ge0 I see what you are talking about. To enable that is just a matter of adding the optional `GroupKind.Local` argument. I'll edit the code.

Comment: @Ge0 Also, does this solution run faster than the one you wrote took over a half hour for 300 rows?

Comment: Yes, of course : around 1 min versus more than 30. but as the output is perfect when working from Excel, I get 2 strange behaviours with my data coming from a SharePoint list : Group.Local doesn't seem to work, and the sorting is completely lost ! I gonna give up... thanks for your time and trying to help

Comment: @Ge0 Are you perhaps using Direct Query when you connect to Sharepoint? Can  you change it to Import mode? I don't know all the limitations of Direct Query but there are certainly some.

Comment: thanks for this tip, but AFAIK DirectQuery is not available for SharePoint Lists... I mark your answer as ok since it works (with Excel data source)

Comment: @Ge0 I had been thinking that if you **had** DQ, it might be messing things up. Unfortunately, I don't have/use Sharepoint so cannot check to see what the issue is here.